# Аргументы setTimeout в JavaScript и NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, settimeout, таймер

**UPD:** *этот вопрос никакого отношение к "дубликату" не имеет. Меня интересуют конкретные случаи и целесообразность использования нижеупомянутого аргумента. Почему пометили как дубликат не понимаю*

Этот вопрос касается и других таймеров в NodeJS и JavaScript, но возьмем в качестве примера `setTimeout` из NodeJS.

Как известно из [документации Nodejs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/timers.html#timers_settimeout_callback_delay_args), `setTimeout` принимает в качестве аргументов:

1. `Callback` функцию;
2. `Delay` - кол-во миллисекунд, после которого функция будет выполнена;
3. `...args` - массив аргументов, которые передаются в Callback функцию при её вызове через заданное кол-во миллисекунд.

Вопрос:

В каких случаях требуется передавать массив аргументов (`...args`), если в любом случае `Callback` функция может взять необходимые переменные из глобальной области видимости и спокойно с ними работать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Когда Вы не хотите создавать замыкание, захватывающее переменные из области видимости, или
2. Когда значения переменных из области видимости могут измениться к моменту вызова колбэка `setTimeout`.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что Callback функция, которая вызывается таймером как-бы вызывается из того окружение, где она была объявлена и при каждом вызове заново собирает значения всех переменных? И как раз из-за этого и происходит вы указали у себя в ответе п. 2. Но тогда непонятно, почему this меняется, если контекст тот же

Comment: @JohnKent `this` внутри колбэка не является одной из переменных окружения, а определяется исключительно тем, как была вызвана функция